# List meetings under Contact's meetings subpanel - SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

When we go to a Contact's detailed view page, we see the Meetings subpanel that is empty even though we have created meetings with this contact in the past.

However, if we use the "Quick create" form inside the subpanel, the meeting will indeed show up under the subpanel, but not when we create the meeting from the Meetings module.

Does anybody know how to list the Meetings under the Contact's Meetings subpanel ?

Thanks !

BTW, we use SugarCRM 6.1.